# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES errors on Axios GET request In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a mongoDB which contains items in a shop. Using React, I want to render item cards based on each entry in the database. For that matter, I am using Axios for sending a GET request for my server that will handle pulling the data from the database.

My React code is this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
const [items, setItems] = useState([{}]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/item').then(res => {
       (res.data).forEach(entry => {
           setItems(prevItems => {
               return [...prevItems, entry];
           })
       });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
})

return (
    ...
)
}
```

I'm having success getting the data, but in my Chrome console I get non-stop ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES errors which eventually leads to Chrome crashes. Why is this error happening? I am using useEffect() since the React docs says it is the equivalent to componentDidMount() in functional components. What alternative can I use?

Edit: When I remove the useEffect(), the errors keep coming and using the React dev tools I see that in items I have 80 entries which means the request is triggered 10+ times and I don't understand how.

Thanks!

Comment: You make the request after every render

Comment: @zb22 But even if I remove the useEffect() it still stays the same

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make the request after every render.
add `[]` as second argument of `useEffect()` in order to make the request once after first render.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{}]);
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/item').then(res => {
       setItems(res.data)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, VSCode giving me a warning saying that "useEffect has a missing dependency: 'items'. Either include it or remove the dependency array". When I either add 'items' to the array or remove the array, the problem returns. What can I do with this warning then?

Comment: @ZivAviv you can ignore this, or put whole code in `useEffect()` in a function and then call it from `useEffect()` itself, `useEffect(() => {const func = () => {...}  func() }, [])`